# How to grep a column and add it in dictionary key as value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have been working in excel and i am trying to fetch a dictionary with keys and values .This is my table:

```
int1           int2         int3    int4         int5

core_6  2       22           32     core_8      23.34.34.45

72.20.20.20     11           33     core_7      core_work

255.255.255.0   12           12     core_12     44
```

I am trying to make as:

```
{'int1' : 'core_6' '72.20.20.20' ,'255.255.255.0' 'int2': and so on}.
```

The issue i am facing with my code is:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xlsx')
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xlsx', on_demand = True)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name("GlobalInfo")

my_dict = {}
for i in range(2):
    row = worksheet.row_values(i)
    my_dict[row[1]] = row[1::]

d =dict((k, v) for k,v in my_dict.items() if k is not None and k != '')

for x in d:
    print(d[x])

my_di = {k: '' for k in d[x]} 
print(my_di)  ////take all the int1 as keys
worksheet.cell_value(0, 1) 
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
curr_row = 1
kk = []

while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row += 1
        row = worksheet.row(curr_row)
        kk.append(row[1].value)

print(kk)     ///this will print value of 1st row
```

But i am not able to add values to the keys i have made.

Also i am not able to get values of other rows.

Comment: Your example result dict is not valid Pyton. Do you mean to use lists as values: `{'int1' : ['core_6', '72.20.20.20', '255.255.255.0'], ...}`?

Comment: yes i want to use it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Hacker solution, step by step:

1) Save the Excel file as a .csv file to 'myfile.csv'

2)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
```

3) The pandas dataframe can now be handled like a dictionary, you can for example call
`df['int1']` to print the associated column

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach using openpyxl:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#load file
wb = load_workbook(filename='input.xlsx', read_only=True)
# select sheet
ws = wb["GlobalInfo"]

data = {}
# build data dict, using column index as dict key saving header title
for idx, header in enumerate(list(ws.rows)[0]):
    data[idx] = {"title": header.value, "items": []}

# put each cell value
for row in list(ws.rows)[1:]:
    for idx, cell in enumerate(row):
        data[idx]["items"].append(cell.value)

# set header titles as dict keys 
data = dict([(y["title"], y["items"] ) for x, y in data.items()])
```

Comment: this is generating for only the first row and not for all the rows.